# jQuery how to select all elements within the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have question & answer section on my website (FAQ).

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="faq">
   <div class="container">

     <!-- FAQ 1 -->
     <h3><a href="">My FAQ 1</a></h3>
     <div><p>Answer to MY FAQ 1</p></div>

     <!-- FAQ 2 -->
     <h3><a href="">My FAQ 1</a></h3>
     <div><p>Answer to MY FAQ 1</p></div>   

     <!-- FAQ 3 -->
     <h3><a href="">My FAQ 1</a></h3>
     <div><p>Answer to MY FAQ 1</p></div>

   </div>    
</div>
```

And the jQuery looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".faq h3 a").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().toggle();
        return false;
    })
});
```

This works fine but what I need is that if someone clicks on any one FAQ & that if any other FAQ is opened then the same should close automatically.

I tried doing this

```
$(".faq h3 a").not($(this)).hide();
```

But it does not work.

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/as5t604g/

Comment: Thanks. It workes fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe not the most elegant use of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".faq h3 a").click(function(){
        var isVis = $(this).parent().next().css('display') == 'block';
        $(".faq h3 + div").hide();
        $(this).parent().next().toggle(!isVis);
        return false;
    })
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/as5t604g/1/)

> This should toggle correctly, i.e. click on an open FAQ it will close it

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted. :)

Comment: @Pappo Welcome to stackoverflow. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Comment: @Jaromanda Sure, Thanks for information this as I was not aware about this. :)

Comment: @Pappo not sure why you're saying "sure" to me, it was someone else that suggested you mark an answer as accepted - I don't beg for acceptance:p

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want.

**Explanation:** Close them first and then open the clicked one.

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".container div").hide();
  $(".container div:nth-of-type(1)").show();

  $(".faq h3 a").click(function() {
    $(".container div").hide();
    $(this).parent().next().show();
    return false;
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq">
  <div class="container">

    <!-- FAQ 1 -->
    <h3><a href="">My FAQ 1</a></h3>
    <div>
      <p>Answer to MY FAQ 1</p>
    </div>

    <!-- FAQ 2 -->
    <h3><a href="">My FAQ 1</a></h3>
    <div>
      <p>Answer to MY FAQ 1</p>
    </div>

    <!-- FAQ 3 -->
    <h3><a href="">My FAQ 1</a></h3>
    <div>
      <p>Answer to MY FAQ 1</p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

> Note: For transition effects you could use `slideToggle('slow,fast, x ms')`

Comment: `Close them first and then open the clicked one` - so, no need to `toggle()` just `show()`

Comment: the point of the observation is that I think the OP wants the FAQ to toggle on clicking it

Comment: I think OP never mentioned **only using toggle**, so i guess this works same as `toggle`.

Comment: you're right, he didn't ... but his original code would toggle each FAQ, whereas your code would only open, never close the one clicked

Comment: Glad that it helped you!

Comment: @Pappo Welcome to Stackoverflow. If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.